# How to parse the JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, api

I'm in trouble with parsing `JSON`.
The characters of outputs are garbled.

Please tell me to  how to solve this problem.
What become the problem is the next point.

```
NSLog(@"Dictionary '%@'",dictionary); // ◀︎ here
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webservice.recruit.co.jp/hotpepper/gourmet/v1/?key=4f46fcd28f4b15e3&lat=34.678&lng=135.52&range=5&order=4&format=json"];
NSString *urlUTF8=[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlUTF8];

NSString *jsonString=[self performServerRequestWithURL:url];


NSDictionary *dictionary=[self parseJSON:jsonString];
NSLog(@"Dictionary '%@'",dictionary); // ◀︎ here

}

-(NSString*)performServerRequestWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
NSError *error;
NSString *resultString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(resultString == nil){
    NSLog(@"ダウンドード失敗:%@",error);
    return nil;
}
return resultString;
}

-(NSDictionary*)parseJSON:(NSString*)jsonString
{
NSData *data=[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error;
id resultObject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];


if([resultObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
    NSLog(@"its an dictionary");
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary=(NSDictionary*)resultObject;

} else {
    NSLog(@"its probably a array");
    NSArray *jsonArray=(NSArray*)resultObject;
        }



return resultObject;
}
```

Comment: you are returning `return resultObject;` but it should be `return yourDicName`;

Comment: @iPatel , You'r right .

Comment: Thank you for answering this question.
Should I replace [return resultObject] with [return jsonDictionary]?
But it doesnt'work well,sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOur code is perfect you just have to return dictionary in stead of resultobject as @iPatel said.

Replace this code in your code..

```
-(NSDictionary*)parseJSON:(NSString*)jsonString
{
    NSData *data=[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSError *error;
    id resultObject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary;
    if([resultObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
        NSLog(@"its an dictionary");
        jsonDictionary=(NSDictionary*)resultObject;
        NSLog(@"jsonDictionary : %@",jsonDictionary);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"its probably a array");
        NSArray *jsonArray=(NSArray*)resultObject;
        NSLog(@"jsonArray : %@",jsonArray);
    }
    return jsonDictionary;
}
```

But your code contain NSArray also does that means json can be either array or dictionary than you have to change your return type to id so you can return any item.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I try this code,but characters of outputs are as follows.
 \U8cb8\U5207\U53ef \Uff1a\U4f55\U306a\U308a\U3068\U3054\U76f8\U8ac7\U4e0b\U3055\U3044\U3002....

Comment: The problem is with chinese text. When you convert json chinese text is not converted right.